# Arduino bluetooth module connection dropping

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth, arduino

I am using an HC_05 Bluetooth module and an Arduino Uno to try and set up a simple bluetooth connection with my Windows Phone (HTC 8X). I am following the online tutorial [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_communicating_with_Arduino_using_Bluetooth).

When I go into settings, my phone sees the "HC_05" bluetooth signal. I click on it, and it  connects right away. **It stays connected for 5-10 seconds, then suddenly disconnects.**

I am thinking that my phone is not receiving any data from the bluetooth module, and thus deciding that the signal is worthless, and dropping it. But even if that, why? When I call `btSerial.read()` from the linked code, isn't that talking to the device?

The Arduino Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const int TX_BT = 10;
const int RX_BT = 11;

SoftwareSerial btSerial(TX_BT, RX_BT);

//Frequency to send periodic messages to Windows Phone, in milliseconds.
//Core code.
const unsigned long periodicMessageFrequency = 5000;
unsigned long time = 0;

//Process the incoming command from Windows Phone.
//It should be changed according to what you want to do.
void processCommand(char* command) {
}

//Send a message back to the Windows Phone.
//Is can't be changed.
void sendMessage(char* message) {
  int messageLen = strlen(message);
  if(messageLen < 256) {  
    btSerial.write(messageLen);
    btSerial.print(message);
  }
}

//Send a set of periodic messages to the Windows Phone.
//It should be changed according to what you want to do.
//This message could be a sensor data, like a thermometer data.
void sendPeriodicMessages() {
}

//Setup Arduino function
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("USB Connected");
  btSerial.begin(9600);
}

//Loop Arduino function
//It can't be changed
void loop() {
  if(btSerial.available()) {
      int commandSize = (int)btSerial.read();
      char command[commandSize];
      int commandPos = 0;
      while(commandPos < commandSize) {
        if(btSerial.available()) {
          command[commandPos] = (char)btSerial.read();
          commandPos++;
        }
      }
      command[commandPos] = 0;
      processCommand(command);
  }
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();
  if((currentTime - time) > periodicMessageFrequency) {
    sendPeriodicMessages();
    time = currentTime;
  }
}
```

The HC_05 is connected as follows:

```
GND -> GND
3.3V -> 3.3V
RX -> D11
TX-> D10
```

Comment: Try to write a char every tot, so you will reset timeout. if that work, it meand  that a really aggressive energy saving politics kick in.

Comment: It breaks the connection after 5-10 seconds with both my phone and my computer. That makes me think it is on the Arduino side, more likely that it is not transmitting anything at all. I have `Serial.println("test");` in my `loop` function, and the serial monitor shows that going out fine. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Arduino's code and connections?

Comment: code seems fine, please note that module work at 3,3v, so RX and TX should be converted from 5V to 3.3V and 3.3V to 5V.
Also USB only maybe is not giving enouth current, try using an external power supply for the arduino!

Comment: Have you tried connecting the Arduino to your computer via Bluetooth? You can then see a) does it disconnect? and b) try send and receive from a serial monitoring tool

Answer (score 1):

You connect the HC-05 with the Arduino directly with the Tx-Rx line. HC-05 is supposed to be driven on 3.3v and not 5 volts.
Your Arduino Tx pin will supply 5v signal on the HC-05's Rx line which is above the recommneded level. Try putting a voltage converter between the Arduino Tx pin (5v) and HC-05 Rx pin(3.3v).

Maybe there is internally a protection that resets the microcontroller inside HC-05 when voltage goes above 3.3.